# Pub furniture terminology

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the shelves that hang above the bar in some traditional pubs (usually to hold glasses)?

Comment: Are you thinkling of shelves that the glasses stand upright on or the racks where the glasses hang down?

Comment: Re @KillingTime 's question, I see "upside-down stemware holder/glassware storage" and "Upside Down Glass Hanging Organizer"

Comment: [This image](https://i.etsystatic.com/25214121/r/il/9e0ab1/2588146139/il_1588xN.2588146139_3s3g.jpg) shows the difference between a shelf and (here) a rack. It's a **glass rack**.

Answer (score 1):

> **backbar** *noun*
>
> **2** : the shelf or counter space along the wall or backing of a bar area
>
> <sub>Source: [*Merriam-Webster* —
> backbar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backbar)</sub>

Here's one such: https://assets-prd.punchdrink.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Article-Julio-Bermejo-Tommys-Mexican-Restaurant-San-Francisco-Tequila-Collection.jpg